# React - Infinite scroll - scroll doesn't appear when open the application in big screen like TV/projector

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented infinite scroll & am facing this one issue.

I have set page size as 30, So for each API response I receive the 30 data. The problem is, when I open the application on a big screen, like a TV/projector, the initial API call loads the 30 data & no scroll appears due to the large screen. But I have 1000 data in Database.

I told the team, we could increase the initial page size 100, then they asked suppose after increased size what if the scroll doesn't appear on the window. Moreover, they want to keep page size as 30 only, do not want to change it.

How to solve when I open the application on a big screen, load the data until the scroll appear?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just load more data when you first run the app if the screen is bigger...

```
if (screen height > (specific screen size) {
   load initially 60 items (or whatever number works)
} else {
  load normal size of 30 items
}
```

So you will be able to scroll and trigger the infinite scroll with the normal +30 items

Or you can just increase the rows height if you have a big screen height...

Comment: Thanks. I tried this way, it wasn't working properly. 
I loaded initial with 100 items for bigger screen, then we opened application in bigger screen, it's loaded 100 rows but scroll didn't appear. So I want to first find the row count like How many rows should I load inside table to appear the scroll & then call API with that row count. 
How to find the row count to appear scroll based on screen size?

Comment: It really depends on your structure, your rows container must be a fixed size like for example 90% of your screen height, if your screen has a height of 1000px your rows container will be 900px. Now you should use a fixed size for the row height, lets say it is 100px, so now you can calculate the number of rows to fill your rows container: (rowsContainerHeight)/(rowHeight) = number of rows to fill container